# Laravel: npm Exit Code 1 code ELIFECYCLE on CentOS

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm

I'm running `npm run dev`and `npm run watch` both resulting with exit status 1

```
[user@server sub]$ npm run watch

> @ watch /home/example/public_html/sub
> npm run development -- --watch


> @ development /home/example/public_html/sub
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js "--watch"

/home/example/public_html/sub/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:375
    const optimizeFn = async (compilation, chunks) => {
                             ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token (
    at NativeCompileCache._moduleCompile (/home/example/public_html/sub/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:240:18)
    at Module._compile (/home/example/public_html/sub/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:186:36)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
    at require (/home/example/public_html/sub/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:161:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/example/public_html/sub/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/cjs.js:3:16)
    at Module._compile (/home/example/public_html/sub/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:192:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
    at require (/home/example/public_html/sub/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:161:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/example/public_html/sub/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/builder/webpack-default.js:1:82)
    at Module._compile (/home/example/public_html/sub/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:192:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
    at require (/home/example/public_html/sub/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:161:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/example/public_html/sub/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/builder/WebpackConfig.js:5:28)
    at Module._compile (/home/example/public_html/sub/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:192:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
    at require (/home/example/public_html/sub/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:161:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/example/public_html/sub/node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js:27:21)
    at Module._compile (/home/example/public_html/sub/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:192:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ development: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js "--watch"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/example/.npm/_logs/2020-03-01T23_38_53_281Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ watch: `npm run development -- --watch`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ watch script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/example/.npm/_logs/2020-03-01T23_38_53_300Z-debug.log
```

I tried to clear npm cache I wasn't able due I have latest NPM version

```
[user@server sub]$ npm cache clear
npm ERR! As of npm@5, the npm cache self-heals from corruption issues and data extracted from the cache is guaranteed to be valid. If you want to make sure everything is consistent, use 'npm cache verify' instead. On the other hand, if you're debugging an issue with the installer, you can use `npm install --cache /tmp/empty-cache` to use a temporary cache instead of nuking the actual one.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you're sure you want to delete the entire cache, rerun this command with --force.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

For my NPM version

```
[user@server sub]$ npm -v
6.14.1
```

For Node Version

```
[user@server sub]$ node -v
v6.17.1
```

I'm stuck couldn't find a solution, any help please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`terser-webpack-plugin` requires node >= 8.9.

AFAIK `async()` was added to node in 8.x.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I've upgraded NodeJS now I have 12.x however when running the command `npm run watch` freezes at screen `> @ development /home/example/public_html/sub
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js "--watch"`

Comment: After upgrading Node, it is probably rebuilding. If it's "frozen" too long, I recommend removing your `node_modules` folder and reinstalling.

Comment: I'm thankful Darryl however this didn't resolve the issue. I'm still searching for a way out.